# Is an elementary extension of a standard model also standard

Tags: model-theory

Suppose we have some set theory $T$ and a standard model $M$ of $T$. If $M'$ is an elementary extension of $M$, is $M'$ also a standard model? What if $M$ (resp. $M'$) is transitive/complete?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard model" in this context?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Membership in the model is real membership in the external set theory, not some other relation.

Comment: Then the answer is obviously negative to all questions, given that standardness isn't isomorphism-invariant.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I figured this was an easy yes or no, hence asking here instead of MO, but I don't understand what isomorphism invariance has to do with this situation (undoubtedly due to my ignorance of model theory). Could you expand a bit?

Comment: @AlecRhea: It's not that complicated. Fix a standard model $M$ and a proper elementary extension $N$ such that there are two elements $a,b\in N\setminus M$ which don't have the same elements (this can be done assuming $M$ is infinite and satisfies extensionality). Let $N'$ be a model with the same universe as $N$, but with $a$ and $b$ swapped. Then $N$ and $N'$ can't both be standard.

Comment: AlecRhea, sorry for my late reply. @tomasz is exactly right. The point is that standardness (as you've defined it - which I believe **is** standard - as opposed to merely "well-founded," which I've seen occasionally) cannot possibly be guaranteed by isomorphism(-over-$M$)-invariant conditions like "is an elementary extension of $M$."

Comment: Note that there is a tight connection between well-foundedness and standardness, however: if $M$ is a well-founded (and set-sized) model of a large enough fragment of $\mathsf{ZF}$ (actually extremely little - fun exercise!), then $M$ is isomorphic to a transitive standard structure $S_M$. Moreover, both $S_M$ and the isomorphism between $M$ and $S_M$ are unique! This is the **Mostowski collapse lemma**. Note the "transitive" bit: for example, if $M\preccurlyeq V_{\omega_2}$ is countable, then $M$ is standard but nontransitive so distinct from its Mostowski collapse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that your background set theory (the one you use to define the real membership relation $\in$) is ZFC, though certainly much less would work.

No matter what you assume about $M$ there will be non-standard elementary extensions of $M$.  For instance, let $U$ be a countably incomplete ultrafilter on some large enough infinite set.  Then the ultrapower $M^U$ is an elementary extension of $M$, but $M^U$ will not be well-founded (it is a standard result that $M^U$ is well-founded iff $U$ is countably complete).  That is, if we let $E$ be the membership relation of $M^U$, there will be an infinite descending $E$-chain of elements of $M^U$ (See the answer/comments at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14622/how-can-an-ultrapower-of-a-model-of-zfc-be-ill-founded-yet-still-satisfy-zfc for why this still happens even if $M$ satisfies the foundation axiom).  Since the real membership relation is well-founded, $E \neq \in$, and $M^U$ is non-standard.

Comment: Thank you -- it looks like completeness might interact with the argument outlined in the linked MO post; can the extension be complete (i.e. transitive and correctly computing powersets) and still fail to have sequences of its members?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that - hopefully someone else will be able to reply.